# Return a value from a pushed view controller

Tags: xcode, return-value

In my code, I've customized the initWithNibName to receive some data it needs to do it's thing.  Here's the code:

```
    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil theArray:(NSArray *)theDataArray theVal:(NSInteger)theDataValue bRange:(BOOL)isRange bColor:(BOOL)isColor{

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.data = theDataArray;
        self.selectedValue = theDataValue;
        NSLog(@"NCG - initWithNibName setting selectedValue = %d.", self.selectedValue);
        //self.originalValue = theDataValue;
        self.isTheRange = isRange;
        self.isTheColor = isColor;
        self.selectedIndex = [self indexFromValue:theDataValue bRange:self.isTheRange bColor:self.isTheColor];
        self.doneClicked = NO;
        //NSLog(@"Selected Row = %d.", self.selectedIndex);
    }
    return self;
}
```

When this view runs, it updates self.selectedValue to a new value.  I need this value in the view that pushed this view once this view is popped.

How do I get this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have this I usually have a 'parentReference' data member
ex:

```
#import "A.h";
#import "B.h";

            @implementation A

                - (void) f
                {
                  B *bInstance = [[B alloc] init];
                  bInstance.parentRef = self;

                  [self.navigationController pushViewController: bInstance];
                }
```

//while 'B' class is declared like

```
@class A;
@interface B : UIViewController
{
  A *parentRef;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) A *parentRef;
```

that way, you can go back to the class that 'summoned' you and do whatever you want

(you might think that `[self.view superview] == parentRef` , but that's not true)

Comment: This got me to correct the issue I was having, so I +1'd it and marked it as the answer.  My issue was that the values I was passing in via the initWithNibname were local to the function pushing the new view.  Once I made them global to the calling view, everything worked.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I'm glad I could help, as I myself have learned a lot from this site. Good luck!